# -canOpenUrl OSStatus fout -10814

Tags: ios, iphone, url-scheme

I'm trying to open an app from my own app that is also installed on my iPhone called KIJK. I've added the `kijk` string to the array in the Info.plist and am calling the `-canOpenUrl` method but it always fails.

I get this error message:
`OSStatus fout -10814`

Now I'm wondering, in Safari it is possible to open the KIJK app with a link that is made up like this: `kijk://serie/123311` so I assumed `kijk` was the query I needed to add in my plist file.

Is there a way to find out the app scheme of an app I didn't develop? I checked a lot of answers already but they all seem outdated because of new iOS or iTunes versions.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>kijk</string>
    <string>rtlxl</string>
    <string>npo</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: *Is there a way to find out the app scheme of an app I didn't develop? I checked a lot of answers already but they all seem outdated because of new iOS or iTunes versions.*

There is no way for you to find out the **URL Schemes** of another app until unless they declare. For example, Facebook, Uber, etc. Click the link to see Facebook apps URL Schemes.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9 => Whitelist Facebook Apps

*Q:Now I'm wondering, in Safari it is possible to open the KIJK app with a link that is made up like this: kijk://serie/123311 so I assumed kijk was the query I needed to add in my plist file.*

If the KIJK app had URL scheme with the format like "kijk://" then it will open the app. Otherwise, it is not going to open the app.

I guess you might be aware of the rule that from **iOS 9 you need to whitelist the schemes your app will query using canOpenURL.**

Comment: I am aware of the whitelisting, that's what I meant with the `kijk` I added added to my Info.plist. But I still get that OSStatus error..

Comment: I guess the problem is with the URL scheme. Did you get KIJK scheme from the developer or how did you get the scheme of another app? If the KIJK app did not register any scheme like "kijk://" with OS, then canOpenURL will give the same error as you are facing.

Comment: Yeah I think that's the problem too but the developers are not responding and because of the link from Safari that started with `kijk://` I assumed it was registered with that scheme but `-canOpenUrl` fails everytime so it's probably wrong..

Comment: Yes. That's the only case. Is the link is opening the app from safari...let me know? If that is the case, they have registered with OS but some problem in whitelisting.

Comment: I did not see that it is opening in Safari. If something is opening in Safari means, it should register URL Scheme with OS. Please check the whitelist in info.plist. define <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>kijk</string>
</array>

Comment: Yeah if I go to `www.kijk.nl` in Safari and select an episode I get a banner on the top with an "Open" button. If I longpress that button I can see and copy the link (which starts with kijk://) and then it opens the KIJK app from Safari.

Comment: 1. Share your whitelisted info.plist. 2. As you know that the app is available, just try to open the app with "kijk//"..from your app . let me know the results.

Comment: I've added the part for whitelisting in my Info.plist. I've also tried just hardcoding "kijk://" in the `-canOpenUrl` method but didn't work either.

Comment: Did you try to open the app with "kijk://"...instead of checking canOpenUrl ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016275/canopenurl-fails-but-openurl-succeed?rq=1

Comment: seems to be a weird issue. According to this,https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=10814 the scheme was not registered. but I'm wondering why it is working in safari.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts.. Then I ended up here but I know it's a though question.